# AWS SNS pubs from the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function i'd like to invoke from the client-side.  I was going to use the API Gateway, but it occurred to me that the queuing SNS affords might be handy.

After researching, it appears the only way to publish to SNS thru the Javsacript SDK is auth thru google/facebook or AWS Cognito.  I'd like users (more specifically, events) to be able to push w/o auth'ng, so that's not an option.

The last option is hard-coding an AWS key.  This is pretty explicitly discouraged in the docs, but after looking into it, it looks like I can create security provisions for a specific key and limit it to publishing only to one topic.

In other words, it'd ostensibly mimic a REST API, wouldn't it?

The only drawback I can think of is malicious spamming of the SNS.  I know AWS API allows for rate-throttling, but couldn't find something similar on SNS.

So, 2 related question:

1. Is there a way to prevent malicious spam to an SNS topic?
2. are there other drawbacks to using SNS instead of an AWS API for invoking lambdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What queueing are you wanting to get from an SNS topic? I think you may be confusing SNS with SQS.

I see no advantage to using `SNS->Lambda` in this instance versus `API->Lambda`. I do however see several drawbacks to using SNS in this instance as it adds an unnecessary complication, as well as opens up unnecessary security risks.

You literally get no advantage to using SNS here, while you get several advantages to using API Gateway such as rate limiting and API key support. Not to mention that API Gateway endpoints are **much** easier to access from the browser than SNS topics. This is API Gateway's intended use, why try to hack together some method using SNS and hard coded AWS keys?

Comment: thanks mark! I was thinking of SNS, as SNS will re-attempt delivery if a lambda invocation gets kicked back b/c of concurrency limitations or other causes of execution failure. i was mistaken that this was unique to SNS, though, as it appears lambda itself will retry functions and provides some level of execution guarantee.  ultimately though, i think this was just a case of premature optimization on my part.